# How should i store settings variables in php?

Tags: php, coding-style

I am currently writing a program in php. I want to let the user of my script change some settings, like database location and user.
These variable are placed on the first lines of the script.

Now i want to access these variables from everywhere of the script like in classes and functions.

I used globals for this. But a colleague told me not to use globals.

So what is the common way to store and access settings in php?

Comment: can anybody explain why it is not good to use globals?? thanks

Comment: @bingjie2680 Simple example: You have written an application and implemnted all the logic you need. Now you want to compare the data from db to the data from another, but wait your dbConnect functions uses the global keyword so you can not connect to 2 databses at once! You willl have to copy paste the function and use another global . But your business logic uses the connection returned by dbConnect so you will have to copy paste them and exchange dbConnect with your new function, but the buisnness logic ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use constants which are global by default:

```
define('APPLICATION_SETTING', true);
```

Otherwise you could use a Registry Singleton class in which you load the settings and store them in a class private variable.
Classic Registry class structure:

```
class Registry {
    private $instance = NULL;
    private $vars = array();
    private __construct() {/**/}
    public static function getInstance() {/**/}
    public function get($key) {/**/}
    public function set($key, $value) {/**/}
}
```

And no, I suggest you not to use Injections and stuff patterns. Just use Singleton. With Injection you get everything worse and more complicated.

Comment: Constants are global (as you even say yourself) so I would avoid using those. The Registry pattern can work although it's really global state by another name. If you're using it for config only then I would not have any setters and not make it a singleton. Singletons make code harder to test.

Answer (score 3):

Configuring a script by changing the variables inside the script is a bad idea.

The simplest way to store config setting is by using a .ini file and parse it with the parse_ini_file function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

sample ini:

```
[db]
host = "foo.org"
user = "dbguy"

[session]
timeout = 600
```

If your script is object oriented you should wrap the config setting in a class ... and pass it as a constructor argument to your main class.

Else you can use the global array but please do not use the 'global' keyword in your functions! your functions should accept settings from your functions as parameters.

```
$config = parse_ini_file("protectedFolder/config.ini", true);

//wrong, do not do it this way
function connect(){
  global $config;
  $connection = dostuff($config['db']['user'],$config['db']['host'];
  //do stuff
}

connect();

//right
function connect2($user, $host){
  $connection = dostuff($user, $host);
  //do stuff
}

connect2($config['db']['user'], $config['db']['host']);
```

This is a very simple concept, and there a better ways to do this, but it should get you started and it will do the job for simple apps.

If you need something more sophisticated you should google for "dependency injection"

EDIT: edited comments
EDIT2: fixed missing quotes

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding your text, but aren't you contradicting yourself a little? I quote "but please do not use the 'global' keyword in your functions", but then in your `function connect() ...` you go ahead and do just that?

Comment: You could possibly go further with this by wrapping the config in a class for ease of use (but still pass in specific config variables as needed). You can also use web server configs to set some of the values in the $_SERVER environment in you need per-vhost configs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods. Here are a few options:

- You could use a constant, if the variable isn't going to change.
- You could use a singleton config object (although singletons in general are frowned upon by many; personally I think in the case of global configuration they can be quite useful).
- Also, you can just pass around variables as function arguments.

It really depends on the application you're developing and personal preference. Global variables do tend to get awkward using them in the long run, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple sqlite db in the server maybe to put the configuration settings that can only be reached by your php program. By encapsulating the query of sqlite to one simple class, you dont have to use globals.

Answer (score -1):

You colleague is wrong in this case. Globals are the most convenient way to go about storing settings that need to be available everywhere. That's what a global *is*, something that is available everywhere. PHP is already full of globals, such as `$_REQUEST`. Put your settings in a single global array called `$SETTINGS` is my advice.

Comment: Jeff's solution is the way. Globals are dangerous because they can be accidentally modified. And they require each function to declare the list of imported globals.